# Find hour for each cell in a data.frame of Dates

Tags: r, date, hour

I have a `data.frame` that looks something like that:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date1= dmy_hms(c("06.08.2019 10:00:04", "07.08.2019 12:21:08")),
                 date2= dmy_hms(c("06.08.2019 11:22:17", "07.08.2019 17:44:09")))
df
                date1               date2
1 2019-08-06 10:00:04 2019-08-06 11:22:17
2 2019-08-07 12:21:08 2019-08-07 17:44:09
```

I want a dataframe containing the hour of each cell:

```
expected_df <- data.frame(hour1= c(10, 12),
                          hour2= c(11, 17))
expected_df
  hour1 hour2
1    10    11
2    12    17
```

I've tried different approaches like`lapply(1:nrow(df),function(nrow_i){hour(df[nrow_i, ])})` and `lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), hour)` but none of them worked so far.

Comment: or `df[] <- lapply(df, lubridate::hour)`

Comment: @Clemsang This is great! You can post as an answer and I will accept

Comment: @RonakShah That is great, too! The problem with my approach was that `lapply(1:nrow(df),function(nrow_i){ class(df[nrow_i, ])})` is `"data.frame"`. Why does the much simpler approach that you suggested work?

Comment: that is correct it is because inside `lapply`, columns are treated as vectors. So your approach is similar to doing `hour(df)` whereas with `lapply` it is same as `hour(df$date1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base`:

```
setNames(format(df, "%H"), c("hour1", "hour2"))

  hour1 hour2
1    10    11
2    12    17
```

Have a look at [Date Formats in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/).

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need a loop. Plenty of options from base `lapply` to convenient `purr::map` family of loops, for instance

```
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
map_dfc(df, hour)

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   date1 date2
#   <int> <int>
# 1    10    11
# 2    12    17
```